# autoconf: error: no input file

Tags: software-installation, autoconf

I am trying to install a program I downloaded, [linpac](http://sourceforge.net/projects/linpac/).

I opened the README, and it claimed all I have to do is ./confugure;make;make install but I am stuck on the ./configure because there is no configure file.

There is a configure.ac file, so I ran the command **autoconf** but I was returned with the error:

autoconf: error: no input file

What are the next steps I can take to try to install my program?

Comment: Can you provide a link to exactly what you downloaded? The unpacked `linpac-0.20.tar.gz` tarball appears to contain both a configure script and a configure.ac autoconf source file. Are you sure you are running the commands from the correct directory?

Comment: I downloaded linpac-0.21.tar.gz by simply clicking the green download, and I checked again and I only see the configure.ac

Comment: yes .. linpac-0.21 from sourceforge contains only configure.ac.. which i'm not able to run either

Answer (score 1):

According to the linpac-0.21 README:

```
Release packages can be identified by the presence of the ./configure in
this directory. If the ./configure script is not present, then see the
'Hacking' instructions below.
```

The instructions are:

```
NOTES FOR HACKING
~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
A clean checkout from the GIT source repository is not ready to configure
and compile. You will need the GNU autotools
(https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GNU_build_system) to create the
./configure script and Makfile templates. Once the autotools are
installed the full build procedure is:

    autoreconf --install
    ./configure
    make
    make install
```

So it seems you need to run `autoreconf --install` rather than plain `autoconf`. Alternatively, you could consider using `linpac-0.20` instead, which appears to be the most up-to-date release version.

Comment: do you mean 0.2 instead of 2.0?

Comment: @Skyler440 yes thank you - corrected